# ClassCastException in android database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-asynctask, android-sqlite

I have a `MainActivity` whose `onCreate` is

```
//called when activity first created
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    searchText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchText);
    utils = new Utils(MainActivity.this);
    db=(new SQLLiteDbHelper(MainActivity.this,utils.getInt(Key.Db_version))).getReadableDatabase(); 
    request = new WebRequest(this);
    status = new AsynGetEmployeeStatus();

}
```

and `sqlitehelper onCreate` and `constructor` is

```
//constructor 
public SQLLiteDbHelper(Context context,int dbVersion) {
    super(context,DATABASE_NAME, null, dbVersion);
    this.context = context;
    Log.d("tag","db version is "+DATABASE_VERSION);
    crypt = new Cryptography();
    utils = new Utils(context);
}



//called when activity first created
@Override
public void onCreate(final SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String s;

    try {

        //new LoadData().execute(db);   

        new AsynNetworkOperation(context, ServiceUri.AccessMethod.GET, "loading").execute(ServiceUri.SERVICE_URI+"s?d=abc");  //this line throw exception


    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(context, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.d("tag",t.toString());
    }
}
```

my `AsynNetworkOperation` class is

```
public class AsynNetworkOperation extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{

private Context context = null;
private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
private String title = "";
private WebRequest request = null;
private String accessMethod = "";
private HttpResponse response = null;
AsynResponse delegate = null;

public AsynNetworkOperation(Context context, String method, String dialogTitle)
{
    this.context = context;
    accessMethod = method;
    this.title = dialogTitle;
    delegate = (AsynResponse) context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    dialog.setMessage(title);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    request = new WebRequest(context);
    if(accessMethod.equals(ServiceUri.AccessMethod.GET)){
        response = request.makeHttpGetCall(data[0]);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    dialog.dismiss();
    delegate.responseResult(response);
    dispose();
}

private void dispose()
{
    context = null;
    dialog = null;
    title = "";
    request = null;
    accessMethod = "";
    delegate = null;
}
```

}

`AsynResponse` is

```
public interface AsynResponse {

/**
 * This will called when AysncTask finished its execution or when onPostExecute called
 * 
 * @param response
 */
public void responseResult(HttpResponse response);

}
```

My problem is , whenever sqlitehelper try to execute new `AsynNetworkOperation` in its `onCreate` , it throw exception

**java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.MainActivity**

can anyone help me finding the problem why it is throwing exception.

Thanks

Comment: Post AsynNetworkOperation

Comment: sorry..i think i got the problem. i forgot to implement interface.

Comment: This line `delegate = (AsynResponse) context;` probably causing issue

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK where should i implement interface. in main activity or sqlitehelper.?

Comment: i guess it need to be implemetn in mainactivity. am i right.?

Comment: @wqrahd you have to know. But since you are casting the context, well I suppose yes

Comment: @wqrahd : you need to implement interface in MainActivity

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK but i want to implement it in sqlite helper class. is there any solution?

Comment: @wqrahd : try to implement it in sqlite helper class if you are getting any issue then we will try to help you

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK i have implement it but it again throwing the same exception.

Comment: @wqrahd : Add one more parameter to AsynNetworkOperation constoctor as `AsynNetworkOperation(SQLLiteDbHelper sqlitehelper,Context context, String method, String dialogTitle)` then use `delegate =sqlitehelper;` and execute task as from SQLLiteDbHelper `new AsynNetworkOperation(this,context, ServiceUri.AccessMethod.GET, "loading").execute(ServiceUri.SERVICE_URI+"s?d=abc");` if you are implementing  `AsynResponse` in `SQLLiteDbHelper`

Comment: thats good approach..:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well this looks like it's probably the problem:

```
delegate = (AsynResponse) context;
```

You're casting the `context` variable to `AsynResponse`, and that `context` variable comes from here:

```
new SQLLiteDbHelper(MainActivity.this, ...)
```

So it *isn't* an `AsynResponse`. It's not even clear what `AsynResponse` is, but `MainActivity` presumably isn't compatible with it.

You should work out what you *really* want that value to be, potentially passing it separately to the `Context`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. yes this is the problem. but where should i implement the interface. mean on Sqlitehelper class or on mainactivity class.

Comment: @wqrahd: Well you're casting the `MainActivity` object to `AsynResponse`, so *potentially* there - but we don't really know enough about what you're trying to achieve or even what the interface is meant to represent.

Comment: I want to implement interface on sqlite helper class. how should i do that.i am editing my question and posting Asynresponse interface.

Comment: edited my question. i create this interface to notify me when asyntask finished its execution. so i want to do when asyntask done (in sqlite helper class) its exection, then i need to populate my database but i want to do this in sqlite helper class not in mainactivity.

Comment: how to implement this on sqlitehelper instead of mainactivity.?

Comment: can you please help me.i implement interface in sqlite but it again throw same exception.

Comment: @wqrahd: Stack Overflow doesn't work that way - you asked one question, and I've answered it. It really doesn't work when you then start trying to ask a completely different question. We're not an interactive debugging and design resource. If you want to implement the interface in your Sqlite helper class, just do so - and then pass that instance to the `AsynNetworkOperation` constructor. But if you run into problems doing that, then you need to ask a new question.